# Setting transparency in background colors of neatline fame?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-9.3

Is there an easy way to set transparency levels in background colors of a neatline frame or any other frame for that matter in ArcGIS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A known bug:
http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/17336

and goes back to 2001
http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=93&f=989&t=44348

bit like overprinting never supported

Comment: I actually figured it out using the effects toolbar (transparency)